# How to Convert Dataframe into JSON

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a `dataframe` with 3 fields and i want to convert it in JSON data format.

**Note**: I am using databricks for it.

DF:

```
+-------+----+----------+---------|
|Airline|Type|Account No|Ticket No|
+-------+----+----------+---------+
|     B0|  06|     12345| PNR12456|
|     B1|  07|      4589|  PNR6588|
+-------+----+----------+---------|
```

I want to convert it below JSON format:

```
{
"Airline":{B0,B1...},
"Type":{06,07,....},
"Account No":{1234,4589,....},
"Ticket No":{PNR12456,PNR6588,....}
}
```

I have used below Code used:

```
DF.to_json(orient='records')
```

I want to perform it in Scala Spark.

Answer (score 0):

you can use toJSON method .

```
val dfJSon = DF.toJSON()
```